# Create basic RESTful API Server to a datastore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, nginx

I have the most basic of questions, but the more I think about it, the more complex it gets.

I've been using rails and it follows the MVC paradigm in that db and api calls are abstracted through calls generated through the controller.  This seems way too heavy for what I want.

1) I want a simple (basic) web server that sits in front of my datastore. (The contents of which happen to be stored in a directory structure that follows: /LOCATIONS/LOCATION/PRESENTERS/PRESENTER/YEAR/MN/)

2) I want to be able to host json files within that directory structure and GET them as needed.

3) I want to be able to PUT/POST append to those json files.

Seems like all I'd need is nginx with my datastore as a doc root and index.html files at critical places within the structure (e.g. site.com/Locations/index.html , site.com/locations/SF/presenters/solomon/index.html)?

How would I begin to solve this problem, (without the use of controllers of coarse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVC Frameworks**

> without the use of controllers

You must be aware that there are [**many more frameworks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Ruby) than Rails out there, so when you ask about using a system to *"sit in front of your datastore"*, you're really looking for different frameworks to handle requests, of which there are many.

The problem you have is how do you keep data consistency, whilst ensuring you can handle the relevant API requests (through JSON). The answer is to look at *how* the systems you're examining work.

I can only really vouch for Rails (it's the only framework I've got production apps for) -

--

**Rails**

Creating an [API in Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem) is so simple - I don't know why you'd think about doing anything else

Using the MVC principle might seem bloated to you, but the security, structure and extensibility it provides is unmatched.

Here is how to create an API in Rails:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :api do 
   resources :controller, only: [:update, :create] #-> only PUT / POST
end

#app/controllers/api/your_controller.rb
class API::YourController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json

   def update
      # handle PUT request
   end

   def create
      # handle POST request
   end
end

#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This is all you need - you'll be able to access `domain.com/api/controller.json POST` to create data, and `domain.com/api/controller/4.json PUT` to update it :)

Comment: Okay so I created a controller (called "Media") and an action (called "play")  I also created a Model (called media). I created a folder called "api" and put the media.rb controller in it (#app/controllers/api/your_controller.rb).  Not sure if I took the proper steps?